# SharePoint search not finding someone and job title displaying incorrectly for one person

Tags: sharepoint-2007, mysite

I am the SharePoint administrator for a company. Usually I can find how to fix problems rather easily but this time I am stumped. I have two problems. One of them is there is a person who has a MySite but when you use the people search she does not show up. The second problem is there is another whose job does not show correctly and when you search by job it doesn't show correctly. Its missing one word in the job title. To update profiles we use a data base that stores there information and sends it to a intermediate database when a specific job is run. We use AD groups to determine who gets a MySite.